# Как перемножить два вложенных словаря?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например, стоит задача перемножить два вложенных словаря:

```
V={'п1': [{'благо1': '1', 'благо2': '2'}],'п2': [{'благо1': '3', 'благо2': '4'}]}
Z={'п1': [{'благо1': '10', 'благо2': '25'}], 'п2': [{'благо1': '20', 'благо2': '15'}]}
```

Ответ:

```
OUT={'п1': [{'благо1': '10', 'благо2': '50'}], 'п2': [{'благо1': '60', 'благо2': '60'}]}
```

Вытащить значения из вложенных словарей каждого в отдельности я могу.

```
V={'п1': [{'благо1': '1', 'благо2': '2'}],'п2': [{'благо1': '3', 'благо2': '4'}]}

for i in V.values():
    print(i)
    for j in i[0].values():
        print(j)
```

Но код будет слишком громоздким. Помогите разобраться с этой проблемой.

Comment: Ключи в обоих словарях всегда совпадают?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

In [92]: v = pd.DataFrame({k:v[0] for k,v in V.items()}).apply(pd.to_numeric)

In [93]: z = pd.DataFrame({k:v[0] for k,v in Z.items()}).apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

получились следующие DataFrame's:

```
In [94]: v
Out[94]:
        п1  п2
благо1   1   3
благо2   2   4

In [95]: z
Out[95]:
        п1  п2
благо1  10  20
благо2  25  15
```

их можно перемножить - Pandas "выравнивает" данные по индексам и столбцам:

```
In [96]: v * z
Out[96]:
        п1  п2
благо1  10  60
благо2  50  60
```

и преобразовать произведение обратно в нужный нам словарь:

```
In [97]: {k:[v] for k,v in (v * z).to_dict().items()}
Out[97]: {'п1': [{'благо1': 10, 'благо2': 50}], 'п2': [{'благо1': 60, 'благо2': 60}]}
```

если в результате опять нужны строки вместо числовых значений:

```
In [98]: {k:[v] for k,v in (v * z).astype(str).to_dict().items()}
Out[98]:
{'п1': [{'благо1': '10', 'благо2': '50'}],
 'п2': [{'благо1': '60', 'благо2': '60'}]}
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли!